# how to update a versioned \RequirePackage

Tags: packages, texlive, versions

After an upgrade of Texlive from Debian/testing, the following no longer works:

```
\RequirePackage[ngerman=ngerman-x-2014-05-21]{hyphsubst}
```

How to update this command?

- How to find out the date of the current ngerman package?
- Or how to provide the old package, which is no longer part of the current Texlive distribution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `language.dat` in TeX Live 2017 contains

```
% from dehyph-exptl:
german-x-2017-03-31 dehypht-x-2017-03-31.tex
=german-x-latest
ngerman-x-2017-03-31 dehyphn-x-2017-03-31.tex
=ngerman-x-latest
```

The name `ngerman-x-2014-05-21` was superseded with TL 2016. But the format of `language.dat` tells you that you can always refer to those patterns by

```
ngerman-x-latest
```

and this will work also if the pattern file is updated. So

```
\RequirePackage[ngerman=ngerman-x-latest]{hyphsubst}
```

is the best way.

---

If you want to reproduce the old breaks, I'm afraid you need to edit the `language.dat` file yourself and rebuild the formats.

1. Find a copy of `dehypht-x-2014-05-21.tex` and `dehypht-x-2014-05-21.pat` in an old TeX Live distribution.
2. Save them in `$TEXMFLOCAL/tex/generic/dehyph-exptl`, creating the tree necessary directory tree; `$TEXMFLOCAL` refers to the output of `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFLOCAL`.
3. Run `sudo texmflsr`
4. Append the line

   ngerman-x-2014-05-21 dehypht-x-2014-05-21

   to `language.dat` (you find it by doing `kpsewhich language.dat`)
5. Run `sudo fmtutil-sys --all`

Then `\RequirePackage[ngerman=ngerman-x-2014-05-21]{hyphsubst}` should work.

Comment: @JoachimWuttke One shouldn't rely on “experimental” packages for work that's supposed to be “forever”.

Comment: This answer helped me to solve a problem that I had after the last MikTeX update, which replace said file from 2017 with the file from 2018 without updating the language.dat
This in turn prevented the format files from being build.